# scoping $.each function (binding)

Tags: jquery, scope, bind

I was used to Mootools, that has a bind method.
JQuery's bind() is used for events, as far as I can tell.

So, in a class method, I was used to do this:

```
$.each(items,function(index,item){
 //[...] then here this refers to the class constructor, not item
}.bind(this));
```

How can I do this in JQuery?

Comment: You know `bind` is vanilla JS ?

Comment: Yes but it's only supported by IE9+, and till IE11, I'm still (sadly) supporting IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IE8 answer comes from here:

http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

```
// Credit to Douglas Crockford for this bind method
            if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
                Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
                    if (typeof this !== "function") {
                        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
                        throw new TypeError ("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
                    }

                    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, 1),
                            fToBind = this,
                            fNOP = function () {
                            },
                            fBound = function () {
                                return fToBind.apply (this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                        ? this
                                        : oThis,
                                        aArgs.concat (Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments)));
                            };

                    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
                    fBound.prototype = new fNOP ();

                    return fBound;
                };
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`bind` is vanilla JS.

jQuery provides the [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function for very old browsers not having `bind` (i.e. I.E. 8-)

Note that browsers having the `bind` function also have the `Array.prototype.forEach` one, which makes `$.each` most often useless.

Your loop with `$.proxy`, also working on IE8 :

```
$.each(items, $.proxy(function(index,item){
      // here, this is the outside this
}, this));
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew, but I also need IE8 for now.

Comment: @Stratboy I might have been unclear, I edited to show how to use $.proxy.

Comment: Yes that's a solution for my problem too! Thank you :)